# Download via http and streaming upload to Google Cloud storage using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am fighting to get a download to directly stream to GCS without saving to the file system, see below snippet.

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const http = require('http');
const storage = new Storage();
const fs = require("fs");
const bucketName = 'BUCKETNAMEHERE';
const blobName = 'image.jpg';
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const blob = bucket.file(blobName);

const streamDownload = () => {
    http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg")
        .pipe(blob.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                contentType: 'image/jpg'
            }
        }))
        .on("error", (err) => {
            console.error(`error occurred`);
        })
        .on('finish', () => {
            console.info(`success`);
        });
};
```

On finish is never triggered. No output whatsoever.
I can stream http.get to a local file without problems, so that part seems to be OK.

What also works is streaming from the local filesystem to GCS, like below :

```
const streamFs = () => {
    fs.createReadStream('/path/to/mqdefault.jpg')
        .pipe(blob.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                contentType: 'image/jpg'
            }
        }))
        .on("error", (err) => {
            console.error(`error occurred`);
        })
        .on('finish', () => {
            console.info(`success`);
        });
};
```

The second snippet logs 'success' and the file is present on the bucket.

Both `http.get` and `fs.createReadStream` create a read stream.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the request library works with promises whereas the http lib needs a callback :

```
const streamDownload = () => {

  var stream = blob.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
        contentType: 'image/jpg'
    }
  })

  http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(res){
        stream.on("error", (err) => {
            console.error(`error occurred`);
        })
        stream.on('finish', () => {
            console.info(`success`);
        });
        res.pipe(stream)            
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Switching over to the `request` library does work :

```
const request = require('request');
const streamDownload = () => {
    request.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg")
        .pipe(blob.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                contentType: 'image/jpg'
            }
        }))
        .on("error", (err) => {
            console.error(`error occurred`);
        })
        .on('finish', () => {
            console.info(`success`);
        });
};
```

Still unsure why `http` library does not.